# mapping shortcut in vim without hanging the cursor

Tags: vim

I would like to have vim fill a short sequence of characters into a longer string in insert mode. Example, say I write the word "sub" and it writes "subroutine" as soon as I press space. The problem I find is that when I use `:imap sub subroutine`, every time I start typing `sub`, the cursor does not continue moving, but hangs in the same position waiting for more keystrokes in order to decide what to do. I find this behavior annoying, although not wrong (it does what I need).

Is there a way to have vim continue typing single characters, and eventually replace ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to use abbreviate `:ab sub subroutine`

Comment: I would advise to use `iabbrev` instead of `ab`. This way it only works in Insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

Search the web for "vim completion" (or the help for "completion"). The feature [is in v7.x](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/123-Vim-7-code-completion.html), but you may want to change the keystrokes with `ìmap`.